# GetSpeed() плавное изменение значений в TextView

Tags: android

При получении данных о скорости движения, получаемые данные сильно разнятся. То есть шаг изменения большой. Например с начала движения "0" следующий показатель может быть "20" и так далее. в `TextView` это некрасиво выглядит. Хотелось бы сделать плавный переход от значения к значению. 0,1,2,3,4....,18,19,20 и когда скорость уменьшается аналогично.
Мне в голову пришло только, цикл в потоке с `Thread.sleep(300)` если значение из `TextView`  больше `getSpeed()` то отнимать по 1, а если меньше то прибавлять по 1.
Может есть другой способ попроще?

по совету из комментария
использовал ValueAnimator

```
ValueAnimator animation = ValueAnimator.ofInt(valueStart,valueEnd);
    animation.setDuration(3000);
    animation.addUpdateListener(new AnimatorUpdateListener() {

        @Override
        public void onAnimationUpdate(ValueAnimator anim) {
             Integer value = (Integer) anim.getAnimatedValue();

                textView2.setText(String.valueOf(value));
        }
    });
    animation.start();
```

Comment: [ValueAnimator](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/animation/ValueAnimator.html).

Comment: Спасибо! Это действительно проще и интересней. И открыл для себя ValueAnimator с которым мой проект станет живее.